# Можно ли оптимизировать?

Tags: php, оптимизация, sql

```
function num_tasks_rate($a) {
 $query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `tasks_summ_done` DESC");
 for($i = 1; $i <= $data_rates = mysql_num_rows($query); $i++) {
  $data_rates = mysql_fetch_array($query);

  if($data_rates['vk_id'] == $a) $n = $i;
 }
 return $n;
}
```

Функция получает список всех юзеров из таблицы и сортирует их и выдаёт номер юзера в рейтинге. Можно как-то упростить? Вроде грузит всё быстро, мне для интереса :)

Comment: не совсем понял зачем вы делаете сравнение $data_rates['vk_id'] == $a ??

Comment: @Ale_x честно говоря я этот код вообще не понял)

Comment: Можно, если добавить break.

     if($data_rates['vk_id'] == $a) {$n = $i; break;}

Ведь если нашли, то зачем ещё искать?

Comment: @ModaL А скажите нам, что должна выдавать данная функция? Потому что порядковый номер в абстрактном списке....

Comment: Он у вас работает ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function num_tasks_rate($user)
{
   $r=mysql_query("select count(*) from `users` where `task_summ_done`>(select `task_summ_done` from `users` where `vk_id`=$user)");
   list($rating)=mysql_fetch_array($r);
   return $rating+1;
}
```